# gzip compression in android app as client and php server

Tags: php, android

In my android app i want to send compressed data to php server using gzip compression and receive response from the server and decompress the response if it is compressed. But when i am sending compressed data,server is getting null and not the data which i am sending and it is returning error message.

This is code i am using for compression--

```
 public static String compress(String strData) throws Exception 
{           
ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
            gzip.write(strData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            gzip.close();
            String outStr = obj.toString("UTF-8");         
            return outStr;          
}
```

This is the code used for decomprssion---

```
 public static String decompress(String str) throws Exception 
{    
         byte[] bytes1 = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
         GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes1));
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
            String outStr = "";
            String line;
            while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
              outStr += line;
            }
            return outStr;
      }
```

And I also add a header to httppost request

httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

can anyone please tell me what to do if I want to compress data before sending to server and also receive response and decompress it, if it is compressed.

Comment: We don't see what you send to the server. We don't see your php script. There is too much to gues in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> 

public static void main() {
        String myString = "H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WMuwrCMBSGX0XOnCFpLoZ0ExH0FaTDyU0DTVsSB6H03Y3dHN3+67fCgm8wjAA6dz2DASmjUsjRCs8tahu5FCw6DQQmzKEt";
        byte[] decode = Base64.decode(myString, Base64.NO_WRAP);

```
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode);

    int read;
    try {
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream));
        System.out.println("read222 :" + br.readLine());


        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(gzipInputStream);
        //System.out.println("read222 :" + dataInputStream.retoString());

        for (int i = 0; i < decode.length; i++) {
            read = dataInputStream.readInt();
            int rRead = Integer.reverseBytes(read);
            System.out.println("read :" + dataInputStream.read());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run your code in a thread or asynctask or service whereever you want

```
Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                String body = "Naval is working on zip and unzip processed return json";
                                URL url = new URL("http://yourServerUrl/yourgzip.php");
                                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
                                GZIPOutputStream dos = new GZIPOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                                dos.write(body.getBytes());
                                dos.flush();
                                dos.close();
                                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                                StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(); 

                                String decodedString = "";
                                while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    builder.append(decodedString);
                                }
                                in.close();
                                Log.e("Data", builder.toString());

                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.e("Datae", builder.toString());
                            }


                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
```

on server side ask them to use this code

```
$postdata=gzinflate( substr($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,10,-8) );
```

as `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` deprecated so use file_get_contents() like to return  array

```
$post = array_map('urldecode',explode('&',file_get_contents("php://input")));
```

or like this method to decompress a gzip stream that was pushed to my webserver

```
$x = file_get_contents("compress.zlib://php://input");
```

and using

```
$data_as_associate_Array=json_decode($x,true);
```